# Unable to compile Rust with no_std/lang_items

Tags: rust

I am attempting to set up a project very similar to [dueboot](https://github.com/jensnockert/dueboot).  That is, Rust on embedded ARM.  Right now, I'm only up to the point of compiling the Rust code, but I can't get it to compile.

I've basically copied the rust code exactly from that project, but I don't fully understand the `lang_items` feature.

```
#![feature(asm)]
#![feature(lang_items)]
#![feature(no_std)]

#![no_std]

use arduino::{init, delay, pinMode, digitalWrite, analogWrite, LOW, HIGH, OUTPUT};
mod arduino;

#[lang="sized"]
trait Sized {}

#[lang="copy"]
trait Copy {}

#[lang="sync"]
trait Sync {}

static PWM:u32 = 2;
static LED:u32 = 11;

#[no_mangle]
pub fn main() {
  // ...
}
```

Attempting to compile the code as above, results in this error:

```
main.rs:11:1: 11:15 error: parameter `Self` is never used
main.rs:11 trait Sized {}
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.rs:14:1: 14:14 error: parameter `Self` is never used
main.rs:14 trait Copy {}
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.rs:17:1: 17:14 error: parameter `Self` is never used
main.rs:17 trait Sync {}
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

I also attempted to comment out all of the lines relating to the `lang_items`, including the feature line at the top.  This is the resulting error message:

```
// more lines of the same message
error: requires `sized` lang_item
error: requires `sized` lang_item
error: requires `sized` lang_item
error: requires `sized` lang_item
error: requires `sized` lang_item
error: aborting due to 54 previous errors
```

I'm using rust built from master, as of yesterday.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a wild guess (couldn't compile your code at all): try to make these traits `unsafe`: `pub unsafe trait Copy {}`.

Comment: Still complains that `parameter 'Self' is never used`.  Sorry - the complete code is in the repo above, it just appears to not be working with the latest Rust.

Comment: You might try using `trait Blah : ::std::marker::MarkerTrait`. See: http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.MarkerTrait.html

Comment: @BurntSushi5 That would be a bit difficult, as OP can't use `std` ;)

Comment: I would suggest copying [MarkerTrait](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/2b01a37ec38db9301239f0c0abcf3c695055b0ff/src/libcore/marker.rs#L287-L288) and [PhantomFn](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/2b01a37ec38db9301239f0c0abcf3c695055b0ff/src/libcore/marker.rs#L347-L352), but that seems to cause an LLVM assertion.

Answer (score 3):

A few days ago, Rust added the rule that all type parameters must appear in the methods of the trait ([RFC 738](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0738-variance.md)). But since `Sized` (and `Copy` and `Sync`) doesn't have any methods of its own, it breaks this rule by default.

The official workaround is to mark the trait as `PhantomFn`, which silences the error:

```
#![feature(asm)]
#![feature(lang_items)]
#![feature(no_std)]

#![no_std]

use arduino::{init, delay, pinMode, digitalWrite, analogWrite, LOW, HIGH, OUTPUT};
mod arduino;

// Copied from <http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/marker/trait.PhantomFn.html>
#[lang="phantom_fn"]
trait PhantomFn<A: ?Sized, R: ?Sized = ()> {}

#[lang="sized"]
trait Sized: PhantomFn<Self> {}

#[lang="copy"]
trait Copy: PhantomFn<Self> {}

#[lang="sync"]
trait Sync: PhantomFn<Self> {}

static PWM:u32 = 2;
static LED:u32 = 11;

#[no_mangle]
pub fn main() {
  // ...
}
```

This change should make the code compile again.

### Addendum: What are lang items?

A *lang item* is a symbol that's marked as "special" to the compiler. Some examples are:

- The heap allocator
- Procedures for unwinding on `panic`
- Types and traits that ensure type safety, like `Send` and `Drop` and `PhantomData`
- Traits for operator overloading, like `Add` and `Eq` and `Deref`

You can find a list of them in [`lang_items.rs`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/librustc/middle/lang_items.rs).

These items are critical to the semantics of the language, but are impractical to implement in the compiler itself. So we put them in the standard library instead, with special annotations that tell the compiler where they are.

Now, while you can define these items itself, it's recommended to link to [`core`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/) instead, which declares these lang items for you. But I'm not sure how well that would work with your setup.

Comment: Were you able to get this to compile? I got: `Assertion failed: (isa<X>(Val) && "cast<Ty>() argument of incompatible type!"), function cast, file /Users/shep/Projects/rust/src/llvm/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h, line 237.`

Comment: I did get a minimal example (without the Arduino stuff) to compile -- but having neither Homebrew nor an Arduino, I didn't find it worth the effort to set up the whole toolchain. Besides, I think the assertion is orthogonal and would fit a separate question.

Comment: It works if you compile it as a library (`--crate-type lib`) like the build script does, instead of an executable.