# Runtime Building: String not found in this scope

Tags: string, rust, substrate, rust-no-std

A common problem substrate developers might run into: developing a custom pallet to store the mapping into storage with common types, such as `String`. As an example:

```rust
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, Default, RuntimeDebug)]
pub struct ClusterMetadata {
    ip_address: String,
    namespace: String,
    whitelisted_ips: String,
}
```

On building the runtime, you get this error for every `String`:

```rust
     |
  21 |     ip_address: String,
     |                 ^^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

#### Why are `Strings` not included in scope? And other `std` rust types?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I will be adding an answer to this as a reference. The question is why does this error occur. Tracking here: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/recipes/issues/403

Comment: I don't see how an answer to this question would benefit the current knowledge base in StackOverflow, due to existing questions like: [How can I use the format! macro in a no_std environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50200268/5923139), [Is it possible to use Box with no_std?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37843379/5923139), [When adding `#1[no_std]` to a library, are there any disadvantages or complications for the users of that library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57611219/5923139), [Unable to compile Rust with no_std/lang_items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28649120/5923139).

Comment: (continued) [Can Rust code compile without the standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61034534/5923139), [How to format output to a byte array with no_std and no allocator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39488327/5923139), [A more convenient concatenation with a string literal in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25328310/5923139). Not to mention, the tutorial pages [A `no_std` Rust Environment](https://rust-embedded.github.io/book/intro/no-std.html) and [No stdlib](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.7.0/book/no-stdlib.html).

Comment: Thanks Aplet123 for these references. It does help me a lot! I think the answer below gets to more specifically why this is an issue, and makes this question relevant. Would you agree?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error here is not related to `no_std`, so you probably just need to import the `String` type to get the real errors with using strings in the runtime.

The real issue you will find is that `String` is not encodable by Parity SCALE Codec, which is obviously a requirement for any storage item (or most any type you want to use) in the runtime.

So the question is "Why does SCALE not encode `String`"?

This is by choice. In general, `String` is surprisingly complex type. The Rust book spends [a whole section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-02-strings.html) talking about the complexities of the type.

As such, it can easily become a footgun within the runtime environment that people use `String`s incorrectly.

Furthermore, it is generally bad practice to store `String`s in runtime storage. I think we can easily agree that minimizing storage usage in the runtime is a best practice, and thus you should only put into storage items which you need to be able to derive consensus and state transitions in your runtime. Most often, `String` data would be used for metadata, and this kind of usage is not best practice.

If you look more closely at Substrate, you will find that we break this best practice more than once, but this is a decision we explicitly make, having the information at hand to be able to correctly evaluate the cost/benefit.

All of this combined is why `String`s are not treated as a first class object in the runtime. Instead, we ask users to encode strings into bytes, and then work with that byte array instead.

Comment: If possible, could you please give some detailed side-effects about `String` in substrate? Although it's reasonable from your writing, but I can't get an impressive result.